# Convert nvarchar to int

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to write a query that select some records like below query but `@reseller` is of type `nvarchar` and an error occurs that it can't convert nvarchar to int. How can I solve it?

```
select * from Factor where code in (@reseller)

@reseller is '1,2,3'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function, which splits the strings and returns the intvalue in table.

```
Create Function dbo.CsvToInt ( @Array varchar(1000)) 
returns @IntTable table (IntValue int) 
AS 
Begin 
  Declare @separator char(1) 
  Set @separator = ',' 
  Declare @separator_position int 
  Declare @array_value varchar(1000)
  Set @array = @array + ',' 
  While patindex('%,%' , @array) <> 0 
  Begin 
     SELECT @separator_position = patindex('%,%' , @array) 
     SELECT @array_value = left(@array, @separator_position - 1) 
     Insert @IntTable Values (Cast(@array_value as int)) 
     SELECT @array = stuff(@array, 1, @separator_position, '') 
  End 
Return 
End
```

One of the great things about user-defined functions is that they can be used in a FROM clause. We can use this function like this:

```
SELECT *
From dbo.CsvToInt('1,5,11')

which returns

IntValue    
----------- 
1
5
11
```

In your case you can us like

```
SELECT * 
FROM Factor 
WHERE code IN dbo.CsvToInt(@reseller)
```

Take a look at [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-a-csv-with-an-in-sub-select)

Answer (score -1):

You have to **SELECT** @result and use **CAST** aggregate function to cast it to INT like this‌:

```
select * from Factor where code in (SELECT‌ CAST(@reseller AS‌ INT))
```

Fore more information about CAST aggregate function follow this :
msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx